# Create class notebook fails if group contains disabled users, even if teacher, student sections of create call is empty

Tags: onenote-api, microsoft-graph-edu

Here is the scenario to reproduce the error:

- Take a Microsoft Education Tenant (Demo Tenant is sufficient)
- Create a fresh user with valid office 365 license and usage location
- Disable the account (set block sign-in) to true in Azure Portal
- Create a group and add this user as member

That's the minimum scenario we need. It is also possible to have other (enabled) users within the group, but that doesn't change the behaviour. Now let's follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-classnotebook#create) to create a class notebook:

```
POST https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/myOrganization/groups/{groupId}/notes/classNotebooks/?omkt=de-de
{
    "name": "Class notebook of my group",
    "teachers": [],
    "students": [],
    "studentSections": [],
    "hasTeacherOnlySectionGroup": true
}
```

So, the unified group has just one member with an disabled account, but this specific user is NOT added into the teachers or students section of the create request. Nevertheless the following error message occurs:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (NotFound).
{
  "error": {
    "code": "30109",
    "message": "The following users are invalid: Message: Der angegebene Benutzer disabled.user@mydomain.com wurde nicht gefunden., ServerErrorCode: -2146232832, ServerErrorTypeName: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "@api.url": "https://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C30109"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the clarification from Marc our current procedure is as follows:

- Get a list of all disabled users.
- Enable all of them.
- Wait one minute (cause Graph needs some time to propagate this).
- Create the course notebook through OneNote API.
- Disable all users from the initial list again.

With this everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error message isn't clear but `Teachers` maps `Owners` and `Students` maps to `Members`. So even though you didn't specify this user in the `students` collection, they are a member of the Group and therefore they're considered part of the `students` collection.

When an `30109` error like this is encountered, the only workaround is either iterate through the Owners and Members and remove any disabled accounts, or parse the `message` property for the UPN (`disabled.user@mydomain.com`). It is less than ideal I know.

Comment: That's what it seems to be. But why does the API make me believe I have an influence what users are teachers and students by defining these properties for the request but in fact simply takes the owners and members of the group?

Comment: Because you would normally create a new Class rather than convert an existing Group. Including Teachers and Students allows you to specify membership and roles during class creation.

Comment: But THIS api doesn't allow to be used to create a new class,cause you can apply it only on an existing group (the url has to contain the group id).

Comment: That is correct but it is mostly an unintentional result of changes introduced long after this API landed (i.e. the Graph Rostering and Team APIs). Classes (prior to Teams) were treated similarly to SharePoint Sites in that they were linked to Group but still distinct. With the introduction of Graph Edu, Classes and Groups are synonymous (Class properties are Group schema extensions for example). Classes == Groups, Teachers/Students == Owners/Members, Schools == Admin Units.

Comment: Hopefully, the Class Notebook API will eventually be migrated to Graph where the behavior of Edu OneNote, Teams,  and Rosters can get properly aligned. When and if that happens will depend entirely on developer/customer demand (i.e. it isn't up to me :) )

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and as usual the main problems are legacy reasons. ;-)